# Select into a new table the result s of a complex select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement

```
(select * from xxxx where yyy = '2011') AS a
INNER JOIN
    (select * from xxx where yyy= '2010') AS b
ON a.yyy = b.yyy AND a.xxx = b.xxx)
```

It works.

How can I insert the results which are just one column, into another table?

I tried encompassing this with a `select.... INTO xxx` but it complains about syntax

Comment: your above query will not return any data (not to mention its missing a `SELECT * FROM` at the start). are you looking to create a table with structure similar to `xxxx` but without any data in it? you question is not very clear

Comment: `SELECT * INTO new_table_name FROM table_name` should not throw error. What error it is giving?

Answer (score 0):

While your specific query will not return any results, and the syntax is also wrong, if you're looking for a way to insert data from a `SELECT` statement into a (temporary) table you can do the following:

```
SELECT your_columns
INTO new_table
--or you can use a temp table
--INTO #table
FROM another_table
```

So in your case it would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM
 (select * from xxxx where yyy = '2011') AS a
INNER JOIN
    (select * from xxx where yyy= '2010') AS b
ON a.yyy = b.yyy AND a.xxx = b.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * INTO new_table_name FROM table_name` should work fine.

What is the output if you try:

```
SELECT tmp.* INTO new_table_name FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE yyy = '2011') AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy= '2010') AS b
    ON a.yyy = b.yyy AND a.xxx = b.xxx
)   tmp
```